# i m getting this "String index out of range " 3 error in openbravo

Tags: java, tomcat8, openbravo

**[http-apr-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet - String index out of range: 3
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3**
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.filter(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2780)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1253)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Kit.classOrNull(Kit.java:92)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:159)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:114)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaTopPackage.init(NativeJavaTopPackage.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.buildClassCtor(ScriptableObject.java:1030)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.LazilyLoadedCtor.buildValue(LazilyLoadedCtor.java:110)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.LazilyLoadedCtor.init(LazilyLoadedCtor.java:89)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.sealObject(ScriptableObject.java:1567)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLint.(JSLint.java:113)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLintBuilder.fromReader(JSLintBuilder.java:121)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLintBuilder.fromClasspathResource(JSLintBuilder.java:54)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLintBuilder.fromClasspathResource(JSLintBuilder.java:37)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLintBuilder.fromDefault(JSLintBuilder.java:66)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.JSLintChecker.check(JSLintChecker.java:55)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.ComponentGenerator.generate(ComponentGenerator.java:68)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet.processComponentRequest(KernelServlet.java:242)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet.doGet(KernelServlet.java:188)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.openbravo.base.HttpBaseServlet.serviceInitialized(HttpBaseServlet.java:214)
    at org.openbravo.base.secureApp.HttpSecureAppServlet.service(HttpSecureAppServlet.java:428)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.BaseKernelServlet.callServiceInSuper(BaseKernelServlet.java:88)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.BaseKernelServlet.service(BaseKernelServlet.java:59)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet.service(KernelServlet.java:168)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.openbravo.utils.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.openbravo.utils.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelFilter$1.doAction(KernelFilter.java:62)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:46)
    at org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelFilter.doFilter(KernelFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter$1.doAction(DalRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:46)
    at org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter.doFilter(DalRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
**[http-apr-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelUtils - String index out of range: 3**

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

pls help me any one getting above error in openbravo ??
i m stuck with that error i am trying my best to solve that error but i don't able to solve that so pls help me.. i attched my error log for this.
thank you..
my kernelservlet.java class

```
package org.openbravo.client.kernel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openbravo.base.ConfigParameters;
import org.openbravo.base.HttpBaseUtils;
import org.openbravo.base.exception.OBSecurityException;
import org.openbravo.base.util.OBClassLoader;
import org.openbravo.base.weld.WeldUtils;
import org.openbravo.dal.core.OBContext;
import org.openbravo.portal.PortalAccessible;
import org.openbravo.service.web.WebServiceUtil;


public class KernelServlet extends BaseKernelServlet {
  // private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataSourceServlet.class);
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(KernelServlet.class);

  // this is needed to support logout deep in the code...
  // TODO: make it easier to get to the authentication manager from
  // the
  public static final String KERNEL_SERVLET = "kernelServletInstance";

  private static final String REQUEST_HEADER_IFMODIFIEDSINCE = "If-Modified-Since";
  private static final String REQUEST_HEADER_IFNONEMATCH = "If-None-Match";

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static String servletPathPart = "org.openbravo.client.kernel";

  // are used to compute the relative path
  private static ConfigParameters globalParameters;

  private static ServletContext servletContext;

  /**
   * @return the parameters as they are defined in the servlet context.
   */
  public static ConfigParameters getGlobalParameters() {
    return globalParameters;
  }

  public static String getServletPathPart() {
    return servletPathPart;
  }

  // the inc and dec by passauthentication count must be synchronized
  // and static, there might be multiple kernelservlets and multiple threads
  // may use the same kernelservlet
  private static synchronized void incBypassAuthenticationCount(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    OBContext context = OBContext.getOBContext();
    boolean sessionForThisRequest = context == null
        || session.getAttribute("#Authenticated_user") == null;

    if (sessionForThisRequest) {
      session.setAttribute("forceLogin", "Y");
    }

    if (session != null && "Y".equals(session.getAttribute("forceLogin"))) {
      // session has been created to retrieve a non authenticated component, it might be several
      // non authenticated components sharing the same session, count them to invalidate the
      // session after all of them are done
      Integer count = (Integer) session.getAttribute("forcedSessionsRequestCount");
      if (count == null || count == 0) {
        count = 1;
      } else {
        count += 1;
      }
      session.setAttribute("forcedSessionsRequestCount", count);
      log.warn("The KernelServlet should not be used for unauthenticated access (this request url: "
          + request.getRequestURL()
          + " - "
          + request.getQueryString()
          + "). This functionality is deprecated, "
          + "use 'org.openbravo.mobile.core' instead of 'org.openbravo.client.kernel'; "
          + "see this issue https://issues.openbravo.com/view.php?id=27248 for more information");
    }
  }

  private static synchronized void decBypassAuthenticationCount(HttpSession session,
      HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (session != null && "Y".equals(session.getAttribute("forceLogin"))) {
      Integer count = (Integer) session.getAttribute("forcedSessionsRequestCount");
      count = (count != null ? count : 0) - 1;

      if (count <= 0) {
        session.invalidate();
        log.debug("Invalidating session created for bypass authentication elements");
      } else {
        session.setAttribute("forcedSessionsRequestCount", count);
      }
      log.warn("The KernelServlet should not be used for unauthenticated access (this request url: "
          + request.getRequestURL()
          + " - "
          + request.getQueryString()
          + "). This functionality is deprecated, "
          + "use 'org.openbravo.mobile.core' instead of 'org.openbravo.client.kernel'; "
          + "see this issue https://issues.openbravo.com/view.php?id=27248 for more information");
    }
  }

  @Inject
  @Any
  private Instance<ComponentProvider> componentProviders;

  @Inject
  private WeldUtils weldUtils;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    globalParameters = ConfigParameters.retrieveFrom(config.getServletContext());
    servletContext = config.getServletContext();
  }

  public void service(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    boolean bypassAuthentication = false;

    final String action = request.getParameter(KernelConstants.ACTION_PARAMETER);
    if (action == null) {
      Component component = getComponent(request);

      if (component instanceof BaseComponent && ((BaseComponent) component).bypassAuthentication()) {
        bypassAuthentication = true;
        incBypassAuthenticationCount(request);
      }
    }

    super.service(request, response);

    if (bypassAuthentication) {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
      decBypassAuthenticationCount(session, request);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
      ServletException {

    if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("/" + servletPathPart)) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid url " + request.getRequestURI());
    }

    final String action = request.getParameter(KernelConstants.ACTION_PARAMETER);
    if (action != null) {
      processActionRequest(request, response);
    } else {
      processComponentRequest(request, response);
    }
  }

  // NOTE: this exact same method is present in the MobileCoreComponentServlet in the mobile core
  // module, if changed here, please also check the method in the MobileCoreComponentServlet class
  private Component getComponent(HttpServletRequest request) {

    final int nameIndex = request.getRequestURI().indexOf(servletPathPart);
    final String servicePart = request.getRequestURI().substring(nameIndex);
    final String[] pathParts = WebServiceUtil.getInstance().getSegments(servicePart);
    if (pathParts.length < 2) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No service name present in url "
          + request.getRequestURI());
    }
    final String componentProviderName = pathParts[1];

    final ComponentProvider componentProvider = componentProviders.select(
        new ComponentProvider.Selector(componentProviderName)).get();

    final String componentId;
    if (pathParts.length > 2) {
      componentId = pathParts[2];
    } else {
      componentId = null;
    }

    final Map<String, Object> parameters = getParameterMap(request);
    final Component component = componentProvider.getComponent(componentId, parameters);
    return component;
  }

  // NOTE: this exact same method is present in the MobileCoreComponentServlet in the mobile core
  // module, if changed here, please also check the method in the MobileCoreComponentServlet class
  protected void processComponentRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    Component component = getComponent(request);
    OBContext.setAdminMode();
    String eTag;
    try {
      eTag = component.getETag();
    } finally {
      OBContext.restorePreviousMode();
    }
    final String requestETag = request.getHeader(REQUEST_HEADER_IFNONEMATCH);

    if (requestETag != null && eTag.equals(requestETag)) {
      response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
      response.setDateHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_LASTMODIFIED,
          request.getDateHeader(REQUEST_HEADER_IFMODIFIEDSINCE));
      return;
    }

    try {
      final String result = ComponentGenerator.getInstance().generate(component);

      response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_ETAG, eTag);
      response.setDateHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_LASTMODIFIED, component.getLastModified().getTime());
      response.setContentType(component.getContentType());
      response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CONTENTTYPE, component.getContentType());
      response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_NO_CACHE);

      final PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
      pw.write(result);
      pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      if (!response.isCommitted()) {
        response.setContentType(KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CONTENTTYPE, KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_NO_CACHE);
        response.getWriter().write(KernelUtils.getInstance().createErrorJavaScript(e));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
      ServletException {
    doGet(request, response);
  }

  protected void processActionRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    final String action = request.getParameter(KernelConstants.ACTION_PARAMETER);

    response.setContentType(KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
    response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CONTENTTYPE, KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
    response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_NO_CACHE);

    try {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final Class<ActionHandler> actionHandlerClass = (Class<ActionHandler>) OBClassLoader
          .getInstance().loadClass(action);
      final ActionHandler actionHandler = weldUtils.getInstance(actionHandlerClass);

      if (OBContext.getOBContext() != null && OBContext.getOBContext().isPortalRole()) {
        if (!(actionHandler instanceof PortalAccessible)) {
          log.error("Portal user " + OBContext.getOBContext().getUser() + " with role "
              + OBContext.getOBContext().getRole()
              + " is trying to access to non granted action handler " + request.getRequestURL()
              + "?" + request.getQueryString());
          throw new OBSecurityException("Portal role has no access to this handler");
        }
      }

      actionHandler.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error executing action " + action + " error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      if (!response.isCommitted()) {
        response.setContentType(KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CONTENTTYPE, KernelConstants.JAVASCRIPT_CONTENTTYPE);
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_NO_CACHE);
        response.getWriter().write(KernelUtils.getInstance().createErrorJavaScript(e));
      }
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only GET/POST is supported");
  }

  @Override
  public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
      ServletException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only GET/POST is supported");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  private Map<String, Object> getParameterMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Enumeration keys = request.getParameterNames(); keys.hasMoreElements();) {
      final String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
      parameterMap.put(key, request.getParameter(key));
    }

    if (!parameterMap.containsKey(KernelConstants.HTTP_SESSION)) {
      parameterMap.put(KernelConstants.HTTP_SESSION, request.getSession());
    }

    if (!parameterMap.containsKey(KernelConstants.CONTEXT_URL)) {
      parameterMap.put(KernelConstants.CONTEXT_URL, computeContextURL(request));
    }

    if (!parameterMap.containsKey(KernelConstants.SERVLET_CONTEXT)) {
      parameterMap.put(KernelConstants.SERVLET_CONTEXT, servletContext);
    }

    if (!parameterMap.containsKey(KernelConstants.SKIN_PARAMETER)) {
      parameterMap.put(KernelConstants.SKIN_PARAMETER, KernelConstants.SKIN_DEFAULT);
    }

    return parameterMap;
  }

  private String computeContextURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return HttpBaseUtils.getLocalAddress(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code. And String out of index means your string is not 3 letters long

Comment: @user2004685 Its string out of index and not array out of index

Comment: openbravo is erp system so that code of this are to much so i don't able to post that code @JitinKodian

Comment: @kap By can you post the code, I meant can you post the line which throws the error? Basically this error means your String is of size less than 3

Comment: @JitinKodian i solved my problem thank you for  your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the my answer that not my fault but i use the **tomcat version 8.0.32** and that have bug so for solve this i have **degrade my tomcat version from 8.0.32 to 8.0.26 that solve my problem.**

above error is a bug in [tomcat](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58999) itself. so go through link to solve this.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the log files? Are you getting any error message like `Error executing action` .

Your are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` might be because of `NullPointerException` while converting your exception to java-script-error in below code

`response.getWriter().write(KernelUtils.getInstance().createErrorJavaScript(e));`